# How to fix higher memory utilisation in Django instance running on EC2, is it due to multiple running processes of gunicorn.sock?

Tags: django, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

My Django instance is running on EC2 on top of ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I'm  getting very slow response from my apis, and during debugging i found out almost all of the memory is utilised.

Here is the screenshot for your reference:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-31-22-205:~/Django/user$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            990         860          69          10          60          14
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Top command doesn't said much about the memory utilisation. Here is the output of ps -aux command

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-31-22-205:~/django/user$ ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR<=10{print $0}'
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      8102  0.1  5.8 311428 59216 ?        Sl   05:28   0:03 /home/ubuntu/django/user/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      8108  0.0  5.7 239012 58356 ?        S    05:31   0:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      7254  0.0  5.7 239728 58200 ?        S    May03   0:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      5590  0.0  5.6 239440 57632 ?        S    May02   0:03 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      6929  0.0  5.6 251536 57340 ?        Sl   May03   0:02 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      2039  0.0  5.5 179196 56324 ?        S     2018   2:08 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14416  0.0  5.5 167712 56096 ?        S     2018   1:55 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14461  0.0  5.4 243860 55772 ?        S     2018   1:55 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     13520  0.0  4.5 212172 45860 ?        S    Jan17   1:18 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
```

Here is the output of ps -ef command:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-31-22-205:~$ ps -ef | grep gunicorn
root      2032     1  0  2018 ?        00:27:04 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      2037  2032  0  2018 ?        00:02:14 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      2039  2032  0  2018 ?        00:02:08 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      2111     1  0  2018 ?        00:27:08 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      2186     1  0  2018 ?        00:27:19 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      5585     1  0 May02 ?        00:00:20 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      5590  5585  0 May02 ?        00:00:03 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      5592  5585  0 May02 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      6382     1  0 May03 ?        00:00:15 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      6929  6382  0 May03 ?        00:00:02 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      7254  6382  0 May03 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      7273 14410  0 May03 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      7276  2111  0 May03 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      7296     1  0 May03 ?        00:00:12 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      7304  6382  0 May03 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      7318  5585  0 May03 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      8102  7296  0 05:28 ?        00:00:02 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      8108  7296  0 05:31 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root      8111  7296  0 05:32 ?        00:00:00 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
ubuntu    8189  8168  0 05:48 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
root      9546 14454  0 Jan13 ?        00:01:24 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     13519 14472  0 Jan17 ?        00:01:20 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     13520 14472  0 Jan17 ?        00:01:18 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     13742  2111  0 Jan17 ?        00:01:19 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14410     1  0  2018 ?        00:24:51 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14416 14410  0  2018 ?        00:01:55 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14454     1  0  2018 ?        00:24:58 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14461 14454  0  2018 ?        00:01:55 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14472     1  0  2018 ?        00:25:02 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14476  2186  0  2018 ?        00:01:56 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14483  2186  0  2018 ?        00:01:54 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     14541  2111  0  2018 ?        00:01:55 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     24952 14454  0 Jan28 ?        00:01:08 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     24953  2032  0 Jan28 ?        00:01:10 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     24955 14410  0 Jan28 ?        00:01:11 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     24956 14472  0 Jan28 ?        00:01:11 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
root     24957  2186  0 Jan28 ?        00:01:09 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/django/viago/venv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application -w 3 --bind=unix:/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.sock --preload --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/ubuntu/django/viago/gunicorn.log
```

What i understood from here that multiple instances of gunicorn is running in the background. 
I created one script start_gunicorn.sh to start the gunicorn instance. As far as I understand, I can only start the instance but there is no way with this script to restart or stop the instance. I've two questions here:

1. Is the multiple instances of gunicorn causing the higher memory consumption? If i kill all the pid's and start gunicorn script, would that help and is safe?
2. What is the way to restart and or stop the gunicorn instances?

Comment: Did some fine tuning in the application and cleared all pid's and restart the gunicorn. As of now problem seems to be solved and its working fine for last 4 days with full load. Thank you

Comment: how did you fine tune the application? can you update here please?